# In OpenGL ES 2.0 depth texture buffer is not working when using FBO with texture depth buffer

Tags: c, opengl-es, render-to-texture

Currently I'm working on a project for rendering applications to Framebuffer Object(FBO) first, and rendering back the applications by using the FBO color and depth texture attachments in OpenGL ES 2.0 .

Now multiple applications are rendered well with color buffers. When I'm trying to use depth information from depth texture buffer, it seems not working.

I tried to render depth texture by sampling it with texture coordinate, it is all white. People say the grayscale may differ quite slightly, namely even in the shadow part it's near to 1.0. So I modify my fragment shader to like following:

```
    vec4 depth;
    depth = texture2D(s_depth0, v_texCoord);

    if(depth.r == 1.0)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
```

And without surprise, it's all red.

The application code:

```
void Draw ( ESContext *esContext )
{
UserData *userData = esContext->userData;

// Clear the color buffer
glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Draw a triangle
GLfloat vVertices[] = {  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 
                       -0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f,
                        0.5f, -0.5f,-0.5f };

// Set the viewport
glViewport ( 0, 0, esContext->width, esContext->height );

// Use the program object
glUseProgram ( userData->programObject );

// Load the vertex position
glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices );

glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );

glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 ); 

eglSwapBuffers ( esContext->eglDisplay, esContext->eglSurface );
}
```

So, what would be the problem, if color buffer works fine, while depth buffer doesn't work?

Comment: You're not showing how you set up the texture, bind it, etc. ES 2.0 does not support depth textures, so chances are that you're trying to do something that is simply not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding. I am sure that my hardware supports `OES_depth_texture`. If not, when `glTexImage2D` is called with depth texture, glError will be raised(confirmed on Raspberry Pi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it finally. That reason ends up to be a lack of `GL_DEPTH_TEST` enabling from client applications.

So if you got the same problem, be sure to enable `GL_DEPTH_TEST` by calling `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` during OpenGL ES initialization. By default it's disabled for the sake of performance I guess.

Thanks for all advices and answers.

Answer (score 0):

The depth texture needs to be linearized to be seen in the viewport because it's saved in exponential form. Try this in fragment:

```
uniform float farClip, nearClip;

float depth = texture2D(s_depth0, v_texCoord).x;
float depthLinear = (2 * nearClip) / (farClip + nearClip - depth * (farClip - nearClip));
```

Comment: thanks. Could you explain what are the two uniforms `farClip, nearClip` ?

Comment: near / far clipping planes of the camera used in the perspective matrix.

Comment: So do you mean my depth buffer is alright but only fragment shader has problems? I think, `depth = texture2D(s_depth0, v_texCoord).x;` means to get the first element of a vec4 right? And in my code, `depth.r` means the real depth value. If  `depth.r`  is always 1.0, is it normal? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: depth.x, depth.r, and depth[0] are the same. Depth is always a single float. It looks like this is 1 because you havent converted from exponential depth to a linear depth value using the above equation. Please accept my answer if it help you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test your method and tell tomorrow. I'm not using a perspective matrix transformation explicitly, so how can I get the clipping planes information?

Comment: Try near = .01 and far = 100-1000